# Recommendations of a linux distro for setting up a server?

Tags: webserver, teamspeak

I have this old Asus eee PC that is currently running Linux Mint. I would like to turn this into a server computer to run a teamspeak server and also a simple website. Are there any linux distros that are optimized for this?

Comment: RHEL or the free derivative CentOS is optimized for long-term stability and integrates experience from the Fedora platform. I recommend it for ease of use.

Comment: See [what type of questions should I avoid asking](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask).

Comment: @jasonwryan I disagree with the decision to put this question on hold. Selection of distro for servers is an important issue that has many aspects that are not related to opinion, such as the degree of support for the server hardware in various distros. Another criterion is the degree to which the distro supports automated installation, or requires manual installation of non-free firmware.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Linux distros in general are very customizable, so you can actually make any distro into a server. I don't think there is one distro that can be said to be the best.

For a server I would pick a stable and reliable distro, like Arch Linux. If you are more used to debian-based distros (like Linux Mint), I would recommend Debian or Ubuntu Server.

Distros from Red Hat are also common to see, their free distros are quite good and there are lots of people using them (which is good when you need help).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'll look into Arch Linux to see what I think. But I'll probably stick with things more similar to what I'm used to. Thanks for the input.